# xcorr function with impulse response

Tags: matlab, filtering, convolution

I'm trying to design a Wiener filter in Matlab for a deconvolution problem but I'm having a lot of problems. I have a gaussian white noise process with a variance of 1.2 and a impulse response which has length two. Its values are g(0) = 5 and g(1) = 4. Later on in the process I try to determine Rxx(m). For this I need to calculate g(m)*g(-m) (convolution) and have been advised to use the xcorr function in Matlab but my results don't make sense. Can anyone help me with this xcorr function and with advice on how to use this impulse response in this? I have tried working with the fourrier transforms of g but this has been no help.

Comment: Rxx(0) is in the middle (`ceil(M/2)`)

Comment: Please provide the code you have already tried with. Any we need more details about the context. Like input signal, what the impulse response is for, and where/why you calculate conv(m,-m).

Comment: I don't have an input signal, just that it is a white noise process with variance 1.2 which is passed through a FIR filter g(n). Knowing that this is a FIR filter the difference equation becomes _r(n) = sum g(k) y(n-k)_ . But the signal r(n) is contaminated by a noise process d(n) with variance 0.2. For this I have x(n) = r(n) + d(n).

Comment: This signal is what I want to process with a Wiener filter in order to retain an approximation of y(n). In order to calculate these I need the autocorrelation of x(n) and this is Rxx = 1.2 g(m) * g(-m) + 0.2 d(m). Now I don't have much of a code yet because this is where I struggle: what way should I implement g(m) and g(-m) and perform that convolution. Multiplying the fourrier transforms doesn't seem to work and I have been advised to use the xcorr function but I don't understand how this would exactly work and Matlab's explanation is not much help.

Comment: I shold add that i'm not to experienced with matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code implements only a part of what I can see in the description. It generates the noise processes and does what is described in the first part. The autocorrelation is not calculated with the filter coefficients but with the actual signal.

```
% generate noise process y
y = randn(1,N) * sqrt(1.2);

% filter y with the fir-filter g
g = [2, 0.6];
r = filter(g,1,y);

% generate noise process d
d = randn(1,N) * sqrt(0.2);

% x is the sum of r and d
x = r + d; 

% autocorrelation of x
[Rxx,lagRxx] = xcorr(x);

% plot autocorrelation
figure; grid on;
plot(lagRxx,Rxx);
title('Biased Autocorrelation of Signal x');
xlabel('Lag');

% cross correlation between x and y
[Rxy,lagRxy] = xcorr(x,y);

% plot crosscorrelation
figure; grid on;
plot(lagRxy,Rxy);
title('Biased Crosscorrelation of Signal x and y');
xlabel('Lag');
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I was using the xcorr function completely wrong. My last problem is that after Rxx is determined I want to determine the Wiener filter and for this I need _Ryx_. Now from the previous equations I determined that _Rxy = g(m) * Ryy = sy g(m). Now _Ryx_ should be _g(-m) * Ryy_ right? I tried using _Ryy = xcorr(y)_ and then the conv() function but my results don't make sense.

Comment: @Dann Wabeke: I edited the code to calculate the cross correlation as well.

Comment: But if I would like to go a different way, not using random signals for _r(n)_ and _y(n)_, I could circumvent using unknown signals by deducing the formula's mathematically as I have done. And so I have:                           _Rxx = sy g(m)*g(-m) + sd delta(m)_                                                                _Rxy = Rry = g(m)*Ryy = sy g(m)_                                                                    _Ryx = sy g(-m)_                                                                                               Calculating these without y and r is my problem.